# dagger appears in ggplot in viewer, but replaced with ... when saved to pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` to create a dotplot. One item label has a dagger (†). The dagger appears in the plot when viewed in RStudio, but it is replaced with ... when I save the plot to pdf. Is there a way to prevent the graphics device from converting my dagger to ...?

Here's a small example:

```
library(ggplot2)
# data
  dat <- data.frame(VARIABLES=c("Item 1", "Item 2 †"),
                    est=c(.3, .5),
                    min=c(.2, .4),
                    max=c(.4, .7))
# plot
  ggplot(dat, aes(x=reorder(as.character(VARIABLES), 
                            est), y=est)) +
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=min,
                        ymax=max),
                    linetype="dashed") +
    geom_point(size=3) +
    ylim(-1,1) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position="none") +
    coord_flip()
#---
# dagger appears in viewer
```

[image]

```
# save plot
  ggsave(filename="myfig.pdf")
#---
# dagger replaced with ... in pdf
```

[image]

Comment: See `?pdf`, especially search for "embed fonts" and "problems with PDF output"

Comment: when I run this on Ubuntu 12.04 I get lots of warnings: "In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on 'Item 2 †' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <a0>".  It works if I `library("Cairo"); ggsave("myfig.pdf",device=cairo_pdf)`

Comment: Thanks, @BenBolker. Perfect. That works. I actually need to combine plots and use `grid.arrange`, so instead of wrapping in `pdf()`, I used `cairo_pdf()`. Your tip put me on the right path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from @BenBolker:

> See ?pdf, especially search for "embed fonts" and "problems with PDF output"

```
library("Cairo")
ggsave("myfig.pdf", device=cairo_pdf)
```